# Extract census data using ACS R package for all Zip codes and obtain future projections

Tags: r, census

I have a couple questions about how I can best use the acs R package.  Thanks in advance for your help.

- I would like to build up a comprehensive data frame that is a lookup table with all census data I can get from their API for each Zip code.  Currently I just look up several individual tables using R code like the below example.  Is there a better way of finding all available tables and build up the data table dataset automatically with the column names populated?  I am aware of the acs.lookup function, but I would like to load all the tables and get the data for their zip codes.  Is there a way to get a list of all the tables from the acs.lookup output, or maybe a complete list of the tables that are available?
- I would also like to get future projection data for as many variables as I can get.  I think I can calculate the projections that I found using the above methods using multiple years (2014, 2013, 2012, 2011) and using acs14lite R package for 2014.  Before I do this I am wondering if the US census itself has future projections using this ACS data or something else?

  ### Create user specified geographies

  ## use all zip codes

  zip_geo = geo.make(zip.code = "*")

  ### Create race data frame

  ## get race data

  race.data = acs.fetch(geography=zip_geo, table.number = "B03002", 
                        col.names = "pretty", endyear = 2013, span = 5)

  ## create data frame of the demographics

  zip_demographics = data.frame(region = as.character(geography(race.data)$zipcodetabulationarea), 
                                total_population = as.numeric(estimate(race.data[,1])))

  zip_demographics$region = as.character(zip_demographics$region)

  ## convert to a data.frame

  race_df = data.frame(white_alone_not_hispanic = as.numeric(estimate(race.data[,3])),
                       black_alone_not_hispanic = as.numeric(estimate(race.data[,4])),
                       asian_alone_not_hispanic = as.numeric(estimate(race.data[,6])),
                       hispanic_all_races       = as.numeric(estimate(race.data[,12])))

  zip_demographics$percent_white    = (race_df$white_alone_not_hispanic / zip_demographics$total_population * 100)
  zip_demographics$percent_black    = (race_df$black_alone_not_hispanic / zip_demographics$total_population * 100)
  zip_demographics$percent_asian    = (race_df$asian_alone_not_hispanic / zip_demographics$total_population * 100)
  zip_demographics$percent_hispanic = (race_df$hispanic_all_races       / zip_demographics$total_population * 100)

Comment: Also, just a friendly suggestion. If you use the buttons with your post to format code, links and images right, people will find it easier to follow your posts and respond more often.

Answer (score 0):

You can download a copy of all of the codes in the 2010 table shells at the following link. It will start the download of and excel file when you click on it.

[ACS Table Shells Download](http://www2.census.gov/programs-surveys/acs/summary_file/2014/documentation/user_tools/ACS2014_Table_Shells.xlsx)

what I did was load this document as a data frame, format the column with the appropriate codes and then just use cell addresses example: `povertyNumerator<acsTable[781,2]` to pull in a variable.

you cannot fully automate the process because you need to decide how to break out 'categories' of responses and do your own math, but outside of that you can work pretty quickly with this table and some acs package skills.